# Using setAliasTexParameters and cc.ResolutionPolicy to render a pixel perfect sprite in cocos2d-js

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, cocos2d-js

I'm making my first game with cocos2d-js. I've made a nice title png for my game but when I load it in cocos2-js it has anti-aliasing that ruins the effect. I read on the internet that using setAliasTexParameters can turn off the anti aliasing. I can't get it to work though, I've tried many different ways. I'm sure it's a basic  problem with my syntax but I can't work it out and it's driving me insane. Chrome gives me the error Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'setAliasTexParameters' of null.

Here's the layer:

```
var game = cc.Layer.extend({
    init:function() {
        this._super();

        backgroundLayer = cc.Layer.create();
        this.addChild(backgroundLayer);

        var title = new cc.Sprite.create("assets/ui/title.png");
        backgroundLayer.addChild(title,0);

        title.texture.setAliasTexParameters();

        title.setPosition(160,240);

        }
});
```

EDIT: I have realised the sprites are being made about 30% too big whether I use setAliasTexParameters or not, so pixel perfect anti aliasing ins't possible. I can't work out why this is happening.

EDIT2: If I remove the cc.ResolutionPolicy in my main js file the sprite is rendered perfectly without antialiasing, but my canvas is half the size it should be! I think this is a resolutionPolicy problem rather than a setAliasTexParameters problem.

I haven't been able to find a resolutionpolicy from the documentation that won't resize my sprite.

Comment: http://www.cocos2d-x.org/wiki/Multi_resolution_support, maybe show all?

Comment: Here explains how to add your own way: http://cocos2d-x.org/docs/manual/framework/html5/v2/resolution-policy-design/en